# The import org.apache cannot be resolved error

Tags: java

Here is my code. I am having trouble using the StopWatch.

```
package analysis;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;

public class ThreeSum {

    public static int count(int[] a) {
        int N = a.length;
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
                    if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0)
                        count++;
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {30, -40, 20, -10, 40, 0, 10, 5, -5};
        StopWatch stopwatch = new StopWatch();
        ThreeSum ts = new ThreeSum();
        System.out.println(ts.count(a));
        double time = stopwatch.elapsedTime();
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error
`import org.apache cannot be resolved`.
I am pretty new to Java. Please help

Comment: Few more details are needed to find the error reason. How do you run this code? Is the apache library containing StopWatch on the runtime and compile class path? Do you use some additional build tools (maven,gradle)? What is the exact output you get after trying to run?

Comment: Is it a maven or gradle based probject? what is content of your build.gradle or pom.xml file?